# Application of Rolle's theorem (a corollary of the mean value theorem of differentiation)

Tags: derivatives, induction, rolles-theorem, mean-value-theorem

The following task is given:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f$ be a $n-$times differentiable function. With $f^{(n)}$ we name the nth derivation of $f$.

Show: If there exist $n+1$ different numbers $x_1 < ... < x_{n+1}$ with

$$f(x_j) = 0, \; \; j = 1, ..., n+1,$$

there exists $\xi \in (x_1, x_{n+1})$ with $f^{(n)}(\xi) = 0$.

---

I think this could easily be proved by induction. So the base clause $n = 1$ should be clear, as it is the application of Rolle's theorem on the 1-time differentiable function $f$.

So let's assume that the proposition holds for an $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let's further assume that $f$ is now $(n+1)-times$ differentiable and that there exist n+2 different numbers $x_1 < ... < x_{n+1} < x_{n+2}$, such that
$$f(x_j) = 0, \; \; j = 1, ..., n+2$$

Now by induction hypothesis, there exist $\xi_1 \in (x_1, x_{n+1})$ such that $f^{(n)}(\xi_1) = 0$ and $\xi_2 \in (x_2, x_{n+2})$ such that $f^{(n)}(\xi_2) = 0$ and using the theorem of Rolle again, we should be done in case, that $\xi_1 \neq \xi_2$.

**However** my concept is pretty much over in case that $\xi_1 = \xi_2$.
What could be done to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for a way to improve my inductive proof of a statement derived by Rolle's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035627/looking-for-a-way-to-improve-my-inductive-proof-of-a-statement-derived-by-rolle) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%5E%7B(n)%7D(%5Cxi)%20%3D%200%24&p=1).

Comment: I think you are doing the induction in a bit of a wrong order. Try to prove that $f'$ cancels out on some $x_1<y_1<y_2<y_3< \cdots <y_{n+1}< x_{n+2}$  and then apply the induction to $f'$ which is $n$ times differentiable and vanishes on $y_1 , \cdots , y_{n+1}$.

Comment: @Keen That is the way I would try to solve the problem. Also, note this is basically the approach taken in the answer in my proposed duplicate question.

Comment: For your inductive step, you should be noting that $f’$ is $n$-times differentiable and using Rolle’s Theorem to come up with $x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2 < \ldots < x_{n + 1} < y_{n + 1} < x_{n + 2}$ where $f’(y_1) = f’(y_2) = \ldots = f’(y_{n + 1}) = 0$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You're exactly right! I couldn't find it, but in this case I have to admit that I didn't look carefully enough. Shows me that in the future I have to take closer looks to questions asked before.

Comment: @Keen That's right, and the correct procedure to get this task solved.

Comment: One last question arose: would be if we took n = 0 as base case? Would this work?